# Google Spreadsheet API - find the first empty cell in a column?

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a good way to get the first empty cell in a column from Google's spreadsheet service via Java?

I know I can use:

```
public CellFeed CheckColumn(int row, int col) 
    throws IOException, ServiceException {
    CellQuery query = new CellQuery(cellFeedUrl);
    query.setMinimumRow(row);
    query.setMaximumRow(row);
    query.setMinimumCol(col);
    query.setMaximumCol(col);
    query.setReturnEmpty(true);

    CellFeed feed = service.query(query, CellFeed.class);
    int cell_loc[];

    for (CellEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
       cell_loc=CheckIfEmpty(entry);   
    }
    return cell_loc;
}
```

And walk through the entries, but I'd rather not load the entire column at once, it's slow for my users and it seems bad to just walkthrough the entire column

Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jacob the question is about Java not about Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

This small snippet will create a function in Google Spreadsheet with Google Apps Script:

```
function emptySpace(array) {
  // set counter
  var counter = 0;

  // itterate through values
  for (i in array){
    if (array[i].length > 1) {
      throw ("Only single column of data");
    } else {
      if(array[i][0] != "") {
        counter++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // return value + 1 
  return counter + 1;
}
```

Add this script, via the script editor, to your spreadsheet and the function emptySpace is available throughout the worksheet, like so: `=emptySpace(A1:A7)`.

See example file I've created: [empty space](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdEVfYzJNLTRrdkVpazE2UVBSSGhjLXc)

Comment: The question is about Java, not about Google Apps Script.